# Difference between SynchronousQueue vs TransferQueue

Tags: java, concurrency, queue, producer-consumer

What is the difference between these two implementations? In which cases should be used one over another?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As mentioned in [this post by Alex Miller](http://tech.puredanger.com/2009/02/28/java-7-transferqueue)

> **TransferQueue** is more generic and useful than SynchronousQueue however as it allows you to flexibly decide whether to use normal
>   BlockingQueue semantics or a guaranteed hand-off. In the case where
>   items are already in the queue, calling transfer will guarantee that
>   all existing queue items will be processed before the transferred
>   item.
>
> **SynchronousQueue** implementation uses dual queues (for waiting producers and waiting consumers) and protects both queues with a
>   single lock. The LinkedTransferQueue implementation uses CAS
>   operations to form a nonblocking implementation and that is at the
>   heart of avoiding serialization bottlenecks.

Comment: don't forget to cite the original author of your content when it is not created by you, otherwise it is considered plagiarism

Answer (score 4):

There is one more important point NOT mentioned in Hemz's answer.

From [puredanger.github.io](http://tech.puredanger.com/2009/02/28/java-7-transferqueue) by Alex Miller:

`BlockingQueue` expresses the concept of a queue that:

1. a producer can block when adding items to a queue until there is
   space available.
2. a consumer can block when removing an item from the queue until an
   item exists.

`TransferQueue` takes this one step further and blocks on put until the item is actually consumed by a consumer **(**not just added to the queue**)**. This new constraint is expressed in the key new method called `transfer()`. The name is very descriptive – because the blocking occurs until a hand-off is complete from one thread to another, you are effectively transferring the item between threads (in a way that properly creates happens-before relationships in the Java Memory Model).

From [baeldung.com](https://www.baeldung.com/java-transfer-queue)

> The implementation is actually similar to the BlockingQueue – but
> gives us the new ability to implement a form of backpressure. This
> means that, when the producer sends a message to the consumer using
> the transfer() method, the producer will stay blocked until the
> message is consumed.
>
> **The TransferQueue can be very useful when we do not want an**
> **over-producing producer that will flood the queue with messages,**
> **resulting in the OutOfMemory errors. In such design, the consumer will**
> **be dictating the speed at which the producer will produce messages.**

From [howtodoinjava.com](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/collections/transferqueue-linkedtransferqueue/)

> When a producer reaches to TransferQueue to transfer a message and
> there are consumers waiting to take message, then producer directly
> transfers the message to consumer.
>
> If there is no consumer waiting, then producer will NOT directly put
> the message and return, rather it will wait for any consumer to be
> available to consume the message.

**Other Points:**

Source: [puredanger.github.io](http://tech.puredanger.com/2009/02/28/java-7-transferqueue)

Several other methods are included as well: two forms of `tryTransfer()` that perform a transfer but are either non-blocking (transfer only if it can be done immediately) or with a timeout. And then there are a couple of helper methods `hasWaitingConsumer()` and `getWaitingConsumerCount()`.

`TransferQueue` is more generic and useful than `SynchronousQueue` however as it allows you to flexibly decide whether to use normal `BlockingQueue` semantics or a guaranteed hand-off. In the case where items are already in the queue, calling transfer will guarantee that all existing queue items will be processed before the transferred item.

A paper by William Scherer, Doug Lea, and Michael Scott that lays out the `LinkedTransferQueue` algorithms and performance tests showing their improvements over the existing Java 5 alternatives. `LinkedTransferQueue` outperforms `SynchronousQueue` by a factor of 3x in unfair mode and 14x in fair mode.

Doug Lea says that capability-wise, `LinkedTransferQueue` is actually a superset of `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`, `SynchronousQueue` (in “fair” mode), and unbounded `LinkedBlockingQueues`. And it’s made better by allowing you to mix and match those features as well as take advantage of higher-performance implementation techniques.

Comment: This is very well explained and enough of reference to information.